# EF Inserting data but all GUID turn to same with each other

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
if (tubeCodes.Count > 0) 
{
    foreach (var item in tubeCodes)
    {
        PrepLabSampleTubeVol entity = new PrepLabSampleTubeVol()
                    {
                        SampleId = sample.SampleId,
                        TubeCode = item,
                        Volume = sample.Vol==null ? 0:sample.Vol,
                        VersionNo = 0,
                        TransactionID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        CreatedBy = CurrentUserInfo.LabName,
                        CreatedDttm = DateTime.Now,
                        UpdatedBy = CurrentUserInfo.LabName,
                        UpdatedDttm = DateTime.Now,
                    };
        tubeVolumnList.Add(entity);
    }
}

using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(db))
{
    tubeVolumnList.ForEach(x => uow.Repository<PrepLabSampleTubeVol>().Insert(x));
    //uow.Repository<PrepLabSampleTubeVol>().BulkInsert(tubeVolumnList);
    uow.Repository<PrepLabSample>().Update(sample);
    uow.Save();

    return true;
}
```

When I generated `TransactionID` for each item, they are different with each other, but when codes go to insert, all items' `TransactionID` turns to the same. In the database, `TransactionID` is the primary key of the table.

```
public partial class PrepLabSampleTubeVol:EntityBase,GWZ.Lab.Entity.IAuditableEntity
{
    public Nullable<System.Guid> SampleId { get; set; }
    public string TubeCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Volume { get; set; }
    public int VersionNo { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public System.Guid TransactionID { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDttm { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdatedDttm { get; set; }
}
```

Exception message:

[image: Exception Message]

Quick watch:

[image: QuickWatch]

Comment: EF could be assuming the DB will generate new GUIDs? Can you post the class & model building definitions.

Comment: Updated, please have a look.

Comment: Yeah, for Guid & int key's EF will assume the db will generate a value. (EF core or EF 6??)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#key-types-and-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set an ID column in code, you have to configure EF to *not* expect the ID to be generated. This is done with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public System.Guid TransactionID { get; set; }
```

For GUID ID's it is strongly recommended to allow the database to generate the ID and to use Sequential UUIDs rather than the more randomized format. Assuming SQL Server this would be to define the TransactionId with a default of NewSequentialId() rather than NewId() and configuring the entity with:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public System.Guid TransactionID { get; set; }
```

If you do need to assign the ID in code then it is advisable to generate a sortable GUID suitable for the database storage of UUIDs. For instance for SQL Server and using .Net Core you can use a `SequentialGuidValueGenerator` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.valuegeneration.sequentialguidvaluegenerator?view=efcore-5.0  . There are examples out there for writing your own. For other databases you might need to use a different generator algorithm depending on how the indexing sorts the 128-bit values.  The reason you want to use sort-able UUIDs is to reduce index fragmentation that can occur when things like clustered indexes are built against UUID columns. This can cause index tables to explode in size, hurting performance and requiring frequent index maintenance operations to keep the indexes under control.